# C language link GLFW Why unsuccessful?

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

I am trying to compile with code::blocks IDE using glfw(OPENGEL) but it is not successful.

[image: My image]

After reading the source code, I guess the problem is libgdi32.a.

Is there be other solutions?

I've crawled through other sites, but I do not get answers.

[image: My image]

[image: My image]
Add some messages.

Comment: @leadYet  what id glfw?

Comment: So you guess the problem is because of some library? Have you tried to link with that library?

Comment: Provide build log please.

Comment: @VenuKantSahu It's a library. You can click on the `glfw` tag for some info or just google it.

Comment: It looks like you linked your libraries incorrectly. Remove them from the project and instead add them to the `project build options`->`linker settings`. For example, for `libgdi32.a` you should add just `gdi32`, etc.

Comment: I have done this but have not improved

Comment: It looks to me like you should list the GDI library after the GLFW library on the linker command line.

Comment: Thank you for your help I finally use the dynamic link to the way to give up the static link But the dynamic link even larger than the static? Perhaps I have too little experience

Comment: By the way, when you reply to someone (not under his own post), put @ followed by his hame in the beginning. Otherwise he won't get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

These are linker errors, not compiler errors. Your code has compiled successfully but it contains calls to the Win32 GDI functions `CreateDIBSection`, `CreateBitmap` etc. The linker can't create the final executable (or library) because it doesn't have the library containing those functions.

You need to check your linker's documentation and find out how to tell it where the `libgdi32.a` file is (assuming that you have that file in the first place).

Comment: I know it is a link error that may be my habitual mistake.

Comment: Has been set up inside the file will be put into the link but the problem did not solve ... do not know how to do

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for your suggestion I have already joined the trouble you